# Plant with serrated leaves and orange-red five-petalled flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

I have this in my garden in India.

The flowers will form seeds in 2-3 days mostly. I wanted to know what is its name. The flowers are small and are having somewhat orange color

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited after 2nd photo added:**
Thanks for adding photo of opened flower! With the new photo, obvious what it is - Lesser Mallow (*Hibiscus hirtus*). See more information at http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Lesser%20Mallow%20orange.html
and 
http://indiabiodiversity.org/species/show/229926

*- - - - - - - - - - - - -*
I really *really* wanted to identify your plant as I love a good plant mystery but no luck. I have Indian friends and have helped ID their plants using the Flowers of India site that's been active for 12 years now. Its list of plants is extensive and encompasses both wild and introduced species. Not just smaller plants but vines and trees are included.

I went through 533 plants focusing on flowers that were red to orange and also pink to violet since some flowers have different colour forms but I found nothing that fit. The leaves make me think of a plant perhaps in the Malva genus or the Lavatera genus but I can't find anything that fits.

Since you know what the flower looks like, perhaps you could check the site over. It's www.flowersofindia.net. net
I'm sorry that few of us are familiar with the beautiful flora of your country and so may not be able to give a correct identification.

Comment: Have added new picture now.

Comment: Edited answer after your photo added.

Comment: Thank you so much ,you are very intelligent. Have a great day to you.

Answer (score 4):

They look like hibiscus.
The stamens and petals are really shape like Hibiscus family.

Comment: I thought the same actually.